Microsoft Access (2007-2016) - Form Contents Can't Be Found In Current Record?
I'm currently using Microsoft Access file format "Access 2007 - 2016".
What I'm trying to do is make a form with a combo box, that when a value is selected will populate a list box with results. I have a table with multiple fields, but two relevant ones specifically. The combo box has all possible names that could appear in Field A (drawn from a separate table), and the list box needs to display all values from Field B that correspond to the chosen name. Not all names from the combo box have a corresponding Field B value, and some names have multiple corresponding Field B values.
So far, I've got a macro that runs after the combo box is updated. The macro uses the OpenQuery action, then the Requery action directly after. My current problem resides in this Requery action. When I run the macro, I get an error stating that "There is no field named 'List Box A' in the current record." It also gives the error number: 2109. For the Requery's Control Name, I've triple checked that it's the same as the name shown in the list box's property sheet. What am I doing wrong?
Here's the macro I have converted to Visual Basic
''''
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Load_Mentor_Info
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function Load_Mentor_Info()
On Error GoTo Load_Mentor_Info_Err
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Mentor to Students Query", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
DoCmd.Requery "Students Mentored"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Mentor Clearance Query", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
DoCmd.Requery "Mentor Clearance Display"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Mentor Activity Query", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
DoCmd.Requery "Mentor Activity Display"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Mentor Major Query", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
DoCmd.Requery "Mentor Major Display"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Mentor Occupation Query", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
DoCmd.Requery "Mentor Occupation Display"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Mentor Home Phone Query", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
DoCmd.Requery "Mentor Home Phone Display"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Mentor Work Phone Query", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
DoCmd.Requery "Mentor Work Phone Display"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Mentor Cell Phone Query", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
DoCmd.Requery "Mentor Cell Phone Display"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Mentor Email Query", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
DoCmd.Requery "Mentor Email Display"

Load_Mentor_Info_Exit:
Exit Function
Load_Mentor_Info_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Load_Mentor_Info_Exit
End Function
''''
Edit: The same problem also occurs when trying to requery to text boxes as well, so I'm thinking maybe it's a problem with the form itself? Despite that, I am still able to read the entry on the combo box of the form and use it in a query in the macro.

Please include the macro here.

Sorry, I'm really new to Access. How do I do that?

You said you have a macro. You can copy the macro you have, click EDIT on your post, and paste the macro using the appropriate formatting tools in the post editor. Or do you mean that you are USING a macro but you don't know how to get to it? Is this perhaps a business computer system and a macro a fellow employee wrote?

I have a macro, but it was made in the macro design view so it's like the block programming equivalent of macros. I tried copy-pasting it but the paste was a bunch of jumbled code I think. Do I need to convert it to Visual Basic then copy-paste?

I converted the macro to Visual Basic and added it to the post. Does that help?
